# How to switch from one window to another Chrome window in Selenium using C#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am opening Chrome browser through Selenium web driver using C#. I want to  switch from this opened window to other window which is not opened through web driver (just opening in normal way).

Because as I know we can switch from one window to  an other window only when both are opened by using web driver. But when source window is opened using web driver and destination is not then is it possible to switch?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  There was an issue raised on the project, which was closed as not feasible. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control windows not opened with WebDriver. However, if your goal is to kill other opened windows in order the tests to be executed in a clean environment, you can do it with C# without WebDriver. Also, you can find the name of the windows with C# but you won't be able to control them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i dont need to close that window , i need to work on some functionality on that window which ..

Comment: "I'm going to make a call on this one: it's a browser specific feature, and not something that we can implement in a general way. With IE, it's possible to iterate over the open windows in the OS and find the right IE process to attach to.

Firefox and Chrome, OTOH, need to be started in a specific mode and configuration, which means that just attaching to a running instance isn't technically possible.

Closing as "not feasible" here as this is a browser specific feature." - this is the official statement for this feature request from the WebDriver Community. :)

Comment: is it possible with any other browser?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with WebDriver. However, you can try image-driven test APIs like Sikuli- http://www.sikuli.org/

Comment: Is it possble to use already opened browser so that i can use that browser to run the script using selenium  web driver